# jQuery Selector Troubles

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble coming up with the correct jQuery selector for the following.

```
$(this)
```

equates to

```
<div class="rating-edit" title="Click to edit...">edit rating</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<p class="r-m"><span class="s5"></span></p>

<div class="rating-edit" title="Click to edit...">edit rating</div>
```

What I am trying to do is target the `s5` span inside the `r-m` paragraph class but the number after the `s` can be any number so I can't target it based on it's actual class name.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$(this).siblings('.r-m').child('span').removeClass().addClass('s'+value);
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $(".r-m span") ... but what are you trying to achieve? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(this).siblings('p.r-m').find('span').attr('class', '').addClass('s'+value);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no jQuery `.child`.  I think you mean `.children`.

http://jsfiddle.net/rtgAn/

Comment: ah, thank you, my brain must have melted, no idea why I thought it was `child`....

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).siblings('.r-m').children().first().removeClass().addClass('s'+value);
```

Answer (score 1):

$('span', this).removeClass().addClass('s'+value);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "starts with" selector:

```
.find("[class^=s]")
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H66dW/1)